# DataTable para uma classe

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Sou iniciante em c# e neste momento estou com algumas duvidas sobre como passar a estrutura de um **datatable** para uma classe para mais tarde usá-la, isto para evitar código duplicado visto que tenho varias tabelas que utilizam a mesma estrutura consoante o tipo (condição que tiver a ser usado A ou B). e tava a tentar passar estas estruturas para uma classe em que haveria de ser uma classe que contem Estrutura para o Tipo A ( estrutura do datable e datarows) e B a mesma coisa. Só não sei como passar uma **datatable** para uma classe e depois chamálo no *main*.

Como posso passar esta lógica (Estrutura da tabela ) para uma classe e chamá-la no main?

Estrutura do datatable(exemplo) :

```
nomeTabela.columns.add("...")

(...)

DataRow drinfo = dataTableInfo.NewRow();

  drinfo ["col1"] = var1;

  drinfo ["col2"] = var2;

  drinfo ["col3"] = var3; 

  drinfo ["col4"] = var4;

  drinfo ["col5"] = var5;

  drinfo ["col6"] = var6;

(...)

 datatableX.Rows.Add(drinfo );
```

Comment: Não use DataTable, pesquise por `repository pattern` e seja feliz

Answer (score 2):

Você está procurando o método [DataTable.Clone()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone?view=netframework-4.7.2) que retorna o clone  estrutural de um objeto `DataTable`, incluindo todos os esquemas e restrições atribuídos a esse `DataTable`.

**Uso:**

Após definir a estrutura de um tabela, aqui chamada `tabelaOriginal` basta evocar seu método `clone()`.

```
DataTable tabelaClonada1 = tabelaOriginal.Clone();
DataTable tabelaClonada2 = tabelaOriginal.Clone();
DataTable tabelaClonada3 = tabelaOriginal.Clone();
// ...
DataTable tabelaClonadaN = tabelaOriginal.Clone();
```

Permitindo assim criar uma tabela global onde você possa clonar a estrutura na parte do programa que lhe for conveniente.

Como o objetivo da pergunta é obter informação sobre métodos de replicação da estrutura dum `DataTable`, informo que também é possível salvar a estrutura duma tabela em *Xml* para uso posterior com [`DataTable.WriteXmlSchema(string arquivo)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexmlschema?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_WriteXmlSchema_System_String_), cujo a leitura dessa estrutura pode ser feita com o método [`DataTable.ReadXmlSchema(string arquivo)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.readxmlschema?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_ReadXmlSchema_System_String_).